# does google policy allow to share app?

Tags: android

Does google policy allow us to share other installed app in android device ?

Think we have a app manager, can I make a toolfor user to send\share app ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sharing paid APKs is equivalent to piracy.

Comment: think user backup and share paid apk , does apk on new device work ?